# Imprimir datos repetidos en un arreglo en php

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo con valores repetidos y después los ordeno por valor más alto, en el condicional se imprime el valor mas alto del arreglo "Es 2" pero también quiero que se imprima el valor repetido.

```
<?php
   $fPro = ["0" => 10, "1" => 20, "2" => 40, "3" => 40]; 
    arsort($fPro);
   foreach($fPro as $key => $value){
    $mayorProK = $key;
    $mayorrPro = $value;
    break;
}

   
    if($mayorProK == 0){
        print_r("Es 0");
    }
    if($mayorProK == 1){
        print_r("Es 1");
    }
    if($mayorProK == 2){
        print_r("Es 2");
    }
    if($mayorProK == 3){
        print_r("Es 3");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi aproximación a tu pregunta:

```php
$fPro = [
    "0" => 10,
    "1" => 20,
    "2" => 40,
    "3" => 40
];
arsort($fPro);

echo "Es ".key($fPro)." (".current($fPro).")\n";

foreach (array_count_values($fPro) as $valor => $repeticiones) {
    if ($repeticiones>1) {
        echo "Valor repetido: $valor \n";
    }
}
```

**Explicación:**

Para conseguir la clave del valor más alto después de la ordenación, he usado esto:

```php
key($fPro)
```

pues justo después de la ordenación con `arsort`, el puntero del array se encuentra en el primer elemento, y la función `key`, en el [manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.key.php), dice:

> La función key() simplemente devuelve la clave del elemento del array
> que está apuntando actualmente el puntero interno.

Del mismo modo, para conseguir su valor, he puesto esto:

```php
current($fPro)
```

pues la función `current`, de nuevo en [el manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.current.php), dice:

> La función current() simplemente devuelve el valor del elemento del
> array que está siendo apuntado por el puntero interno.

Y de ahí la sentencia completa, similar a la que ya tenias:

```php
echo "Es ".key($fPro)." (".current($fPro).")\n";
```

donde he agregado el valor entre paréntesis para que se vea más claro.

Luego, para las repeticiones, he usado la función `array_count_values`, que [en el manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php) dice:

> Retorna un array asociativo de valores a partir de array como keys y
> su respectivo recuento como valores.

Por lo tanto, he recorrido ese array asociativo mediante un `foreach` sacando sus pares clave/valor como `$clave => $repeticiones`.

Es decir:

```php
foreach (array_count_values($fPro) as $valor => $repeticiones) {
```

Y dentro de este bucle, en cada iteración, compruebo si el valor de `$repeticiones` es superior a 1, pues si lo es entonces estará indicando que efectivamente hay repeticiones de ese valor, así:

```php
if ($repeticiones>1) {
    echo "Valor repetido: $valor \n";
}
```

y como ves, si se cumple la condición, la salida me muestra el mensaje del valor repetido.